# MVC ajax not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code in my .cshtml:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<span id="status">No status</span> <br />

@Ajax.ActionLink("Server Date", "ServerTime", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "status"})
```

This is the method in controller:

```
 public string ServerTime()
        {
            return "Server date: " + DateTime.Now;
        }
```

When I click the hyperlink, the reponse comes on a different page i.e the DOM is not updated. Instead, I get redirected to `Home/ServerTime`.

Can anybody tell me why is this happening? The script files are correctly downloaded and I checked it in Firebug.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

asp.net mvc 3 by default uses unobtrusive ajax. So you should include script `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`, not the `MicrosoftMvcAjax` ones. As the script is not included, javascript does not parse the ajax link data, so it stays as ordinary link.

Comment: Thanks it worked! but what is unobstusive ajax? and if we should not use MicrosoftMvcAjax ones then why is it mentioned in the tutorial? I think it is for MVC3 only.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript got the very good explanation of the unobtrusive javascript term. And I don't know why it is mentioned in which tutorial. Probably you're missing out asp.net mvc version of tutorial. Unobtrusive ajax is more modern and better to use, more lightweight, so it is default for mvc 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add OnSuccess method parameter in AjaxOptions

Comment: Why? Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533%28VS.98%29.aspx Also what should I write in OnSuccess? It's just takes a javascript function name.